# Is dangerouslySetInnerHTML safe to display JSON string in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, security, next.js

Here is a small code from a NextJs project (React):

```
function MyComponent() {
  myObject = `{"some": "JSON", "thing": "foo"}`;
  return <script type="application/ld+json">{myObject}</script>;
}
```

Using SSR with NextJS it returns a HTML encoded string:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{&quot;some&quot;:&quot;JSON&quot;,&quot;thing&quot;:&quot;foo&quot;}
</script>
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2213) I should do something with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myObject}}/>;
```

Still, the name of the function is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which seems a bit dangerous. And the JSON values comes from a database, so I don't know what it contains (I only know it's text). But I can't see a real scenario where things go wrong with this.

**Is dangerouslySetInnerHTML safe to display JSON string in a script tag?**

Comment: I don't know React well enough to answer this, so just a guess: what if a value in the json data contains `</script><script>alert(1)</script>`? As the browser first parses html, it will match `<script>` to `</script>` regardless of whether it's in a javascript object or a string - javascript processing comes later. Maybe this doesn't apply to your scenario though.